# Converting a too-long answer in a comment should generate an error message

Tags: feature-request, comments

I just tried to convert an answer into a comment; it was too long for a comment, and the software just truncated the text.

> I think it would be better to either generate an error message, ask for confirmation, or possibly generate multiple comments (with ellipses).

Recall only moderators can do this anyway.

Comment: My extremely cumbersome workaround was to repeatedly undelete and re-convert to generate multiple comments, then do some cutting and pasting.  If this process could be automated, I would be grateful.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: So Ideally the process should say "This answer is too long for a single comment, and would require $n$ comments instead. Would you like to proceed? [Yes/No/Burrito]"?

Comment: I think that sometimes comments are slightly overused, and answers are slightly underused. What is wrong to giving partial answers? The problem with multiple comments is that they tend to get scrambled by votes.

Comment: Mmm... burrito.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85796/automatic-splitting-into-separate-comments-during-conversion-from-answer

Comment: @ThomasRot there is nothing wrong with giving a *partial* answer. But some use the answer-box for things that are not anwers *at all.* Also the oerdering can only be off if the comment thread is "collapsed" as there are already too many; so expanding it will solve this problem essentially. And it is rather rare that some other than the first part of a multi-part comment gets the highest score making this even less of an issue.